# Devise add captcha to login page *after* X failed logins

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, devise, captcha

I would like to implement a captcha inside my Devise login form *after*, X failed login attempts ( say 3 )

Has anyone attempted this? 
The only idea I have is storing the failed attempts in a session, then after X failed attempts the  view login page would be complemented with the captcha

This is not failsafe:

- user can reset session
- perhaps sessions do not work, which renders this idea useless.

Is there a good solid way to do this with Devise?

Answer (score 2):

You could store the number of attempts for a given user ID in a cache store (or even persist, depending on the volume of traffic to your site).  Then after X number of attempts, render that partial based on the user's email address.

You would tie it together by doing a check in view or controller for if a key/value pair is set for a given user ID / email address.  If it is and it's greater than your threshold, show the captcha.

Comment: @Rubytastic did this help?  If it did, please close this question by clicking the checkbox next to this answer. :)

Comment: Good one.. I want to know one thing is it possible to escape any captcha if already present on webpage.